# How do i make that only when select ContextMenu "Copy" option it will do something?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the constructor i did:

```
m = new ContextMenu();
m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Cut"));
m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));
m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Paste"));
```

Then i have a ListView mouse click event:

```
private void lstDisplayHardware_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ListViewItem item = lstDisplayHardware.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);


                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Do something to row {0}", item.Position.ToString())));
                    Clipboard.SetText(item.SubItems[1].Text);
                }
                m.Show(lstDisplayHardware, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }
        }
```

When i click on an item from the ListView and then make right click it's selecting the item subitem text and also copy it to the clipboard.

But when i make a right click it also show the ContextMeny options Cut Copy Paste.

I want to do when i make right click only when i click on the "Copy" option it will copy it to the clipboard.

I know that maybe i need to use ContextMenuStrip and create click event for it but then the click event of the ContextMenuStrip will not be connected with the ListView mouse click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every control has a [`ContextMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenu.aspx) property. Try to just set that property on `lstDisplayHardware` to point to your context menu.

```
m = new ContextMenu();
m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Cut"));
m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));
m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Paste"));

lstDisplayHardware.ContextMenu = m;
```

Of course, you want to do that after `InitializeCompnents();` is called.